# java: I want to return snapshot key from inner class but getting empty variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I compare x and y variables with my Firebase database. If i find the right result I want to return the key.

```
private String checkParkeer() {
    final Integer parkX = 4;
    final Integer parkY = 1;
    final String[] result = new String[1];

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("parkeerpaal");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Log.d("test", snapshot.getKey());

                Integer newX = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("x").getValue().toString());
                Integer newY = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("y").getValue().toString());

                if (newX <= parkX+2 && newX >= parkX-2) {
                    if (newY <= parkY + 2 && newY >= parkY - 2) {
                        result[0] = snapshot.getKey();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    Log.d("result", result[0]);
    return result[0];
}
```

Now the `Log.d("test", snapshot.getKey());` logs "P1" (this is the result I need)

But when I put it in result, `Log.d("result", result[0]);`or `return result[0];`give errors.

This is my first time doing this stuff. how do I resolve this? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply return that value outside `onDataChange()` method because this method has an `asynchronous behaviour`, which means that this method is called even before you are trying to get the data from the database. A quick fix in your case would be to use that value only inside `onDataChange()` method or a better solution, would be to use the last part of my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774) in which using your own callback, you can achieve using that value also outside `onDataChange()` method.